# Building a static library in C using the ar cmd

Tags: c, unix, gcc, compilation

I am new to C programming and trying to learn how to build static libraries. I was trying to build an application which suggested me to do the following:

```
gcc -c testFile.c
ar a testFile.a testFile.o
```

When I try to execute these cmds, I get an error: "ar: no operation specified"

I am familiar with simple building of a C file, however I don't understand what the second cmd line does and why we need to do this? I understand about .o files, but why do we need to do "ar a"? Is there a simpler way to do the above and avoid the error?Thank you

Comment: Where did you get `ar a` from `a` is not a valid command, just a modifier for a letter that would preceed it. Generally I'd do `ar rcs testFile.a testFile.o` (r for insert file, c to create a new archive for this action, and s to add symbols to this)

Comment: @SamBob There are other `ar` implementations outside of the GNU one on Linux.  Without knowing where the `ar a ...` command in the question comes from, it's possible an older version of `ar` used `a` to mean "add" or something similar.  [It'd definitely be pre-POSIX, however](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/ar.html).  It wouldn't surprise me if a SunOS 4 `ar` command did just that.

Answer (score 2):

According to [[Man7]: AR(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ar.1.html) (`man ar`):

> **r**        Insert the files *member*... into *archive* (with *replacement*).

For customizations, you could make use of its modifiers (also listed in the above *URL*).

Example:

> ```bash
> (py_pc064_03.10_test2_pycoralcf) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q076052480]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> [064bit prompt]> # Create an object file
> [064bit prompt]> echo "void f() {}" | gcc -x c -c -o dummy.o -
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> dummy.o
> [064bit prompt]> # Create (update) an archive out of it
> [064bit prompt]> ar rs libdummy.a dummy.o
> ar: creating libdummy.a
> [064bit prompt]> ls -Al
> total 8
> -rw-r--r-- 1 cfati cfati 1352 Apr 19 12:08 dummy.o
> -rw-r--r-- 1 cfati cfati 1490 Apr 19 12:10 libdummy.a
> [064bit prompt]> # List archive members
> [064bit prompt]> ar tv libdummy.a
> rw-r--r-- 0/0   1352 Jan  1 02:00 1970 dummy.o
> ```

Comment: Might be worth noting that the `s` option is on by default in most recent versions of ar; its only needed explicitly on very old systems where it was not.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Thanks for the tip. I wasn't aware of that (although I noticed that it also works without it). I used it just out of habit.

Answer (score 0):

tldr: use `ar r your_static_lib.a *.o`

`c` is for creation but `ar` will create the archive anyways when you use r

`s` is for creating an index so you can inspect what's in your library (that is nothing but an `ar`chive of object files) but it's on by default now

You will sometimes see the flags combined under a `-` flag marker, the same you can use `ls -atl` for example but it's a lie. Unlike regulars flags, those are positional and `ar create_me.a obj1.o obj2.o -r` will *not* work.